# What does the left side limit of this function prove?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am currently self-learning the concepts of limits in calculus and I'm trying to comprehend this limit here.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{{x^2-2|x|}}{|x|}.$$

Now, actually computing the limit I get something along the lines of 
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{{x^2-(-2x)}}{-(x)}.$$
Since I am to demonstrate the limit from when $x<0$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{{x(x+2)}}{-(x)}.$$
which ends up being:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}{{-(x+2)}}.$$
Having inputted values from the left side of 0(such as $-0.001$) I notice that it does not touch $-2$. Is it a coincidence that the coefficient of $-2|x|$ is the same as this value? I am trying to verbally explain to myself why is this the case so I can further understand what's going on here.

Thanks alot. Please go easy on me

Comment: Well, it is *not* that coincidence since if instead $\;2\;$ it was $\;7\;$ , for example, then the limit would have been $\;-7\;$ , or if it had been $\;-15\;$ then the limit would have been $\;-(-15)=15\;$ ...

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [graph](http://tinyurl.com/zt659ow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$\frac{x^2-2\vert x\vert}{\vert x\vert}=\frac{\vert x\vert^2-2\vert x\vert}{\vert x\vert}=\vert x\vert-2\xrightarrow{x\to 0}-2$$
so the left and right side limits exist and they are equal. Hence we can extend this function by continiuty on $0$.

Comment: Hm, it seems my algebra is lacking here. Why is it that you can give the absolute value notion to $x^2$? I can see where you went from there however.

Also, offtopic, but nice username :D

Comment: If you don't want use that $x^2=\vert x\vert ^2$ you can compute just the left side limit and notice that the function is even so its right limit exists and equal  to the left one.